# Magento 2.3 Catalog Price Rules Is Not One Of Condition not working

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.3, catalog-price-rules

In Magento 2.3.3 I have created a new product type (based off a simple product) and upto now everything has been working correctly except for this one bug. if I use either Sku Is Not One Of or Is Not as a condition in Catalog Price Rule then the sku that I have added still gets added to the catalogrule_product table for that discount. I've also tried using multiple skus for Is Not One Of and again they don't get excluded. I also tried changing If All These Conditions Are True to False and the doing Sku Is or Sku Is One Of but again the same sku is being discounted and added to catalogrule_product. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can run the command: php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue. It looks like if the product that you want to exclude from the discount is a simple product from a configurable product then you have to also add the configurable product sku to the list to allow it to be removed from being discounted.